# overlaying transparent image to video stream - OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm struggling to understand how to overlay a .png with transparency to a video stream.
For some reason, the transparent area is always displayed as black.
Here's what I do:

Loading the image and setting up the environment

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow("window", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty("window",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
dim = (640,480)
alpha=0.0
foreground = cv2.imread('png.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
rows,cols,channels = foreground.shape
```

Adding an artificial alhpa layer to the frame and overlaying the loaded image

```
def logoOverlay(image,logo,alpha=1.0,x=0, y=0, scale=1.0):
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    image = np.dstack([image, np.ones((h, w), dtype="uint8") * 255])
    overlay = cv2.resize(logo, None,fx=scale,fy=scale)
    (wH, wW) = overlay.shape[:2]
    output = image.copy()
    # blend the two images together using transparent overlays
    try:
        if x<0 : x = w+x
        if y<0 : y = h+y
        if x+wW > w: wW = w-x
        if y+wH > h: wH = h-y
        overlay=cv2.addWeighted(output[y:y+wH, x:x+wW],alpha,overlay[:wH,:wW],1-alpha,0)
        output[y:y+wH, x:x+wW ] = overlay
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: Logo position is overshooting image!")
        print(e)
    output= output[:,:,:3]
    return output
```

Calling this function every frame:

```
while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        frame = logoOverlay(frame,foreground,alpha=alpha,scale=1,y=100,x=100)
        cv2.imshow('window',frame)
```

thanks for your help, highly appreciated!
FP

Comment: can you clarify what you mean about "overlay png with transparency". are you simply overlaying the logo ontop of another image with some alpha you want? or does your png already have an alpha channel and you want to use those values? or do you want to create a png with alpha values? Just trying to understand why you are adding that artificial alpha layer

Comment: I have a 'logo' with a transparent background, that I want to overlay to the video stream From my camera.

Comment: My plan was to add an artificial alpha channel to the RGB frames, so to be able to overlay the logo correctly. Not sure it's a good approach, but the problem is that the logo's transparent pixels show up black.